# c# xml parsing - conversion from php

Tags: c#, xml, api

I currently have my application/project setup on PHP and I am trying to get it working in c# so I can build an application around it.

I have come across some parts of the code which I am looking help with.

1. XML data from: http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&hours=48&typeid=34&typeid=456

Above is XML data from a certain system containing 2 typeids (same as the other XML), again this will be around 100 items at a time.

I am using this code at the moment:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&usesystem=30000142");

var id = from stats in doc.Root.Elements("marketstat")
         from type in stats.Elements("type")
         select new
         {
           typeID = type.Attribute("id").Value
         };

foreach (var itemids in id)
{
  kryptonListBox4.Items.Add(itemids.typeID);
};
```

Which populates the ListBox as 34 and 456.

**What I need is to be able to add the other xml data such as min sell and max buy**

I can get the first min sell like this:

```
string minSell = doc.Descendants("sell")
      .First()
      .Element("min")
      .Value;
```

But I need to have the minsell in relation to the typeID and being able to work with the data.

### Second Problem

1. XML data from http://api.eve-marketdata.com/api/item_history2.xml?char_name=demo&days=10&region_ids=10000002&type_ids=34,456

Above is XML data from a certain region and contains 2 type_ids (this will be a much larger list when completed around 100 items at a time).

I have tried to use similar code as above but I cannot get it to return the correct data.

**I need to be able to get the volume in total for each typeid**

In PHP I use this:

```
foreach ($xml -> result -> rowset-> row as $row)
{
    $id = (string)$row['typeID'];
    $volume = $row['volume'];
    if (!isset($volumes[$id]))
    {
        $volumes[$id] = 0;
    }
    $volumes[$id] = $volumes[$id] + $volume;       
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

//Edit: Looks like I can use

```
var vRow = from xmlRow in marketstats.Descendants("emd").Descendants("result").Descendants("rowset").Descendants("row")
                   select xmlRow;
```

for the 2nd problem but I cannot seem to get the multidimensional array to work

Comment: For your first problem you can have attributes in your xml and query on them

Comment: if you have an xml like this
`<data id='1' >Data1</data>
<data id='2' >Data12</data>
<data id='3' >Data3</data>`
now you can get `data` tag depending on their ids ,exactly like database

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean, the code I have tried I have posted. I have tried getting attribute but it did not work

Comment: checkout my solution it may be close ...

Comment: can you elaborate first problem. sorry i didn't get that perfectly..

Comment: Your code for getting first min is true , but instead of `.First` you can have a `.Where` condition that check its parent tag's `type` id attribute

Comment: I have tried my best to get this working but I cannot seem to get to grasp with the LINQ .Where.  Any other hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second problem if my understanding is right this will be close to ur need.

```
var strxml = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\item_history2.xml");

        var xml = XElement.Parse(strxml);

        var typeIDs = (from obj in xml.Descendants("row")
                       select obj).Select(o => o.Attribute("typeID").Value).Distinct();


        Dictionary<string, long> kv = new Dictionary<string, long>();

        foreach (var item in typeIDs)
        {

            var sum = (from obj in xml.Descendants("row")
                       select obj).Where(o => o.Attribute("typeID").Value == item).Sum(p => long.Parse(p.Attribute("volume").Value));

            kv.Add(item, sum);
        }
```

In the dictionary you will have the sum of volumes against each typeID in such a way

typeID as key and sum of volume as value in Dictionary kv.

For your first problem,

Checkout this,

```
var minsell = (from obj in xml.Descendants("type")
                       select new
                       {
                           typeid = obj.Attribute("id").Value,
                           minsell = obj.Descendants("sell").Descendants("min").FirstOrDefault().Value
                       }
                       ).ToArray();
```

This will give you minsell value in relation with typeid.
I guess this what you expects ?
If wrong please comment it.

Comment: elaborate a bit with any example on first problem i didn't grasp it. I will help you